# How to make a cube in pyglet with images on faces

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm making a 3d game, and i need to paste images on a cube, but I can't find out where the `front`/`back`/`top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` textures should go.

I just started using pyglet, so I'm not very familiar with it. I've been flipping the texture part of the cube for a few days now, and it's still a mess. Here's my code for the cube function below:

```py
def cuboid(self, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2, tex):
    '''
    Draws a cuboid from x1,y1,z1 to x2,y2,z2 and covers each side with tex\n
    tex format:\n
        (front, back, left, right, top, bottom)
    Facing in the -z direction
    '''
    front = tex[0]
    back = tex[1]
    left = tex[2]
    right = tex[3]
    top = tex[4]
    bottom = tex[5]

    tex_coords = ("t2f", (0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1))

    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,back,('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x1,y1,z2, x1,y2,z2, x1,y2,z1, )),tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,right,('v3f',(x2,y1,z2, x2,y1,z1, x2,y2,z1, x2,y2,z2, )),tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,top,('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x2,y1,z1, x2,y1,z2, x1,y1,z2, )),tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,front,('v3f',(x1,y2,z2, x2,y2,z2, x2,y2,z1, x1,y2,z1, )),tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,bottom,('v3f',(x2,y1,z1, x1,y1,z1, x1,y2,z1, x2,y2,z1, )),tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4,GL_QUADS,left,('v3f',(x1,y1,z2, x2,y1,z2, x2,y2,z2, x1,y2,z2, )),tex_coords)
```

I cannot show what I was expecting because I don't have a working 3d rendering program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the coordinates (`x1`, `y1`, `z1`) are the minimum of the cube and the coordinates are the maximum (`x1`, `y1`, `z1`). e.g.:

```py
self.cuboid(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, self.tex)
```

If the cube is drawn in view space, then:

The x-axis points to the left. The `left` texture has to be placed where the x coordinates of all the vertices are `x1` and the `right` texture where the x coordinates are `x2`:

```py
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, right,  ('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x1,y1,z2, x1,y2,z2, x1,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, left,   ('v3f',(x2,y1,z2, x2,y1,z1, x2,y2,z1, x2,y2,z2)), tex_coords)
```

The y-axis point up. So `bottom` is where the y coordinates are `y1` and top where the y coordinates are `y2`:

```py
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, bottom, ('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x2,y1,z1, x2,y1,z2, x1,y1,z2)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, top,    ('v3f',(x1,y2,z2, x2,y2,z2, x2,y2,z1, x1,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
```

In a [Right-handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) system the z axis points out of the view. The z-axis is the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the x-axis and y-axis.
This causes that `front` has to be placed where the z-coordinates are `z2` and `back` where the z-coordinates are `z1`:

```py
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, back,   ('v3f',(x2,y1,z1, x1,y1,z1, x1,y2,z1, x2,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, front,  ('v3f',(x1,y1,z2, x2,y1,z2, x2,y2,z2, x1,y2,z2)), tex_coords)
```

The method `cuboid`:

```py
def cuboid(self, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2, tex):
    '''
    Draws a cuboid from x1,y1,z1 to x2,y2,z2 and covers each side with tex\n
    tex format:\n
        (front, back, left, right, top, bottom)
    Facing in the -z direction
    '''
    front  = tex[0]
    back   = tex[1]
    left   = tex[2]
    right  = tex[3]
    top    = tex[4]
    bottom = tex[5]

    tex_coords = ("t2f", (0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1))

    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, right,  ('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x1,y1,z2, x1,y2,z2, x1,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, left,   ('v3f',(x2,y1,z2, x2,y1,z1, x2,y2,z1, x2,y2,z2)), tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, bottom, ('v3f',(x1,y1,z1, x2,y1,z1, x2,y1,z2, x1,y1,z2)), tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, top,    ('v3f',(x1,y2,z2, x2,y2,z2, x2,y2,z1, x1,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, back,   ('v3f',(x2,y1,z1, x1,y1,z1, x1,y2,z1, x2,y2,z1)), tex_coords)
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, front,  ('v3f',(x1,y1,z2, x2,y1,z2, x2,y2,z2, x1,y2,z2)), tex_coords)
```

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with my computer, everything I try doesn't work.